# why did not search combine key words in Algolia in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5, algolia

working with Laravel 5.6 and mysql and Algolia search. I have been using following `vehicles` table for searching key words,

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model     districtname provincename
1   juy   car           toyota       121       coba         nochiga
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan   natai        sara
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d      zenso        nayou
4   hyu   van           ford         max       mizuri       bakawa
5   nhj   car           toyota       121       nakaga       sara
6   gtr   car           toyota       corolla   wassa        nochiga
7   gtr   van           nissan       caravan   goa          jayui
```

this is my SearchingController function

```
$vehicles =  Vehicle::where('provincename', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')-> orWhere('categoryname', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')-> orWhere('districtname', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')-> orWhere('brandname', 'like', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')-> orWhere('modelname', 'like', '%' .  ->orderBy('adtype', 'DESC')->latest('updated_at') ->paginate(20);
            return view('vehicles.index', compact('vehicles'));
    }
```

this is work for only one key word on each columns like search `car`, `bmw`, `toyota` etc but when I use combine keys like `bmw car` , `car sara` it is not getting results? no any error it is generate following command `no vehiclus display` this is my results generated blade file

```
 @forelse( $vehicles as $vehicule )

                <td>
                    @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" ></a>
                        </a>  

                    @else
                        This vehicule does not have any images attached.
                         <!-- <img src="/images/{{'noimage.png'}}"> -->
                    @endif
                </td>
            @empty
                <td>No vehicules to display.</td>
            @endforelse
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: No any comments here.....

Comment: You are searching ```LIKE``` with ```%search%``` and if you are passing ```bmw car```,```car sara``` etc. So it will look anything which has ```bmw car```,```car sara``` and anything before or after that and no column has these values. That`s why its unable to map with any records.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....how can I fix this problem here?

Comment: Simple way is to check with single word, as you are already doing that or use regex if you want multiple words.

Comment: No any idea to solve this matter?